# WPF => Binding ContextMenu with CollectionViewSource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

Why this is working :

```
<Button x:Name="btnCritereAdd" Content="{Binding Source={x:Static resx:resMain.lblCriterAdd}}" Style="{StaticResource btnStandardClr}" Click="btnMenuPopup_Click" ContextMenuService.Placement="Bottom">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu x:Name="cmuCriteres">
            <ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
                <Binding Path="CriteresDispo" />
            </ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
            <ContextMenu.InputBindings>
                <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick" Command="" />
            </ContextMenu.InputBindings>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

But not this :

```
<Button x:Name="btnCritereAdd" Content="{Binding Source={x:Static resx:resMain.lblCriterAdd}}" Style="{StaticResource btnStandardClr}" Click="btnMenuPopup_Click" ContextMenuService.Placement="Bottom">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu x:Name="cmuCriteres">
            <ContextMenu.Resources>
                <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvsCriteres" Source="{Binding CriteresDispo}"/>
            </ContextMenu.Resources>
            <ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
                <Binding Source="{StaticResource cvsCriteres}" />
            </ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
            <ContextMenu.InputBindings>
                <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick" Command="" />
            </ContextMenu.InputBindings>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

I set the DataContext on Button in CodeBehind:

```
btnCritereAdd.DataContext = vmFiltresChamps;
```

I tried With "UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged" and "NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True" on the two case but nothing is changing.
The list is empty...

Do you have an idea ?

VM side:
Property:

```
public ItemCollection CriteresDispo { get { return _CriteresDispo; } set { _CriteresDispo = value; RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(CriteresDispo)); } }
```

Command called by code behind

```
public RelayCommand<ItemCollection> LoadCriteresCommand { get; set; }

private void LoadCriteres(ItemCollection obj) {
        var ht = new tblFiltreChamps();
        Classes.clsUtils.GetFiltresSel(obj, ht);
        CriteresDispo = new ItemsControl().Items;
        if (ht.items.Count > 0) {
            foreach (var item in ht.items.OrderBy((x) => x.Desc).ToList()) {
                var mi = new MenuItem() { Header = item.Desc, Tag = item };
                mi.Command = AddCritereCommand;
                mi.CommandParameter = item;
                CriteresDispo.Add(mi);
            }
        }
        if (CriteresAddAction != null) CriteresAddAction();
}
```

Comment: Try moving the CollectionViewSource to the buttons resource, resource look up go up the visual tree and horizontal lookup can go peculiar, failing that check your output window for binding errors

Comment: Hello MikeT, i already tried tu put it in button.resource, but nothing change.
What is the horizontal lookup ?

Comment: a horizontal lookup is looking for resources defined in the same level of the visual tree

Comment: I have this message in output :
"System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection' BindingExpression:Path=CriteresDispo; DataItem='ViewModelFiltresChamps' (HashCode=6263136); target element is 'CollectionViewSource' (HashCode=56403320); target property is 'Source' (type 'Object')"
For information, CriteresDispo is ItemCollection type

Comment: the error says the problem is `Source="{Binding CriteresDispo}"` because its a CollectionViewSource try `Source="{Binding CriteresDispo.View}"` instead

Comment: Good idea, but it not this.
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'View' property not found on 'object' ''ItemCollection' (HashCode=52346362)'. BindingExpression:Path=CriteresDispo.View; DataItem='ViewModelFiltresChamps' (HashCode=40764587); target element is 'CollectionViewSource' (HashCode=36662967); target property is 'Source' (type 'Object').
There is not "View" property on ItemCollection object

Comment: Add your VM code to the question

Comment: Also any reason you are setting the data context in the code behind in 99.9999999% of the time you should bind it

Answer (score 0):

`CollectionViewSource` does not implement `IEnumerable`, and therefore cannot be set to the `ItemsSource` property of a `ContextMenu`, which is of type `IEnumerable`.

Therefore you need to change:

```
<ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
    <Binding Source="{StaticResource cvsCriteres}"/>
</ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
```

To:

```
<ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
    <Binding Source="{StaticResource cvsCriteres}" Path="View"/>
</ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
```

This will set the `ItemsSource` to the `CollectionViewSource`'s `View` property, which is of type `CollectionView` and *does* implement `IEnumerable`

Answer (score 0):

> Do you have an idea ?

When binding to a `StaticResource`, the target property won't get updated when you raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the property that is bound to the `Source` property of the `CollectonViewSource`.

That's the difference.

You need to bind to a *property* and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for this specific property for the `ItemsSource` collection to get refreshed.